# Sending dried fruits to Australia through courier

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, mail, prohibited-items

I have sent 1kg of dried fruits as a gift to a friend from New Zealand to Australia. I DECLARED them in customs form when sending parcel through New Zealand post. But now some one now tells me that dried fruits are prohibited items to be sent to Australia.

I am worried that what will happen to that gift? Will they confiscate it? or Am I liable for a fine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.

Comment: @JonathanReez I see it as sort of travel related as it deals with quarantine laws when crossing borders.  In answering the OPs question the same replies would be given if the OP had tried to deliver the food in person via flying NZ->Aus.  And Aus has very strict quarantine rules that people are apparently not aware of.

Comment: @PeterM Postal rules are often very different from border crossing rules, hence this is off-topic.

Comment: @JonathanReez Australia has very strict biosecurity laws that apply to both situations.  A food substance will be banned or permitted regardless of the method of import.

Comment: @PeterM maybe yes, maybe no, but whatever the postal rules are doesn't matter for travel purposes.

Comment: @JonathanReez - lots of travelers ship their purchases home, so imho information like this is applicable to travel.